# Javascript form validation code working on FireFox and Chrome but not on Safari (on radio button)

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

My form validations for radio button is working in Firefox and chrome but they don't show any effect in  safari.

Form is submitted without selected any option.

Comment: Show your code please

Comment: "_i'm on work_" - unfortunetely no one here is psychic, please show some code and/or read this -> http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Upload the code you are using. Safari has problems with same names, try and use a separate id for the fieldset to see if that helps. Then you can troubleshoot from there and you may have to just forget about Safari users since programming in Safari is actually code for Big Game Bug Hunting. Anyone using Safari should be tagged and bagged on your site!